how to get rid of red lines in zed?
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
         GtkWidget *window;
         gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

         window =  gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
         gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Hello World");
         gtk_widget_show(window);

         gtk_main();
         return 0;
}

(clang: 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found)
I can compile this using 'gcc main.c -o mak pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0
./mak'
The problem is that I don't know how to get rid of the red lines.

As I already commented in the staging ground, you need to tell us what zed uses for code completion (which is most likely Clangd). And if it is Clangd, read its manual to know how to configure it: clangd.llvm.org
